# samsung S3 leftswipe and right swipe not working in one touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, samsung-mobile

i created one mobile app with jquery mobile everything is working fine but in samsung phones left swipe and right swipe is not working properly.

its working after 2-3 swipe.

it can be handled with

```
var startCoords;
        $(document.body).on("touchstart", function(event) {
            startCoords = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
        });

        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
            var touchmoveEvent = e.touches[0];
            if(touchmoveEvent.pageX && Math.abs(startCoords.pageX - touchmoveEvent.pageX) > 10)
                e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
```

But if i am adding this code zoom and pinch is not working... any pointer to fix this problem will be very helpful.

note :  problem in all samsung phone but my requirment is for S3 only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var startCoords;
$(document).on("touchstart", function(event) {
    startCoords = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
}).on('touchmove', function(event) {
    var endCoords = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
    if(Math.abs(startCoords.pageX - endCoords.pageX) > 10) {
        alert('Swipe event');
    }
});
```

Checked on S3. Alert works.

Comment: i am not getting please help me to explain or any working example or fiddle ?