# Jquery Mobile Swipe Performance issue

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-mobile, swipe

I got performance issue on mobile phone and tablet on the following link. http://05sch.com/freemagazine/index.php/our-magazines/publication/march-2014-issue/7#page_3

Anyone can share your thought?? Many thanks.

this is the development site, some styling is not very nice, but have to fix the main issue, swipe performance ! Thanks !!

Comment: this is the solution.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740345/samsung-s3-leftswipe-and-right-swipe-not-working-in-one-touch

Answer (score 0):

jQueryMobile allows calibration of the swipe events in this namespace: $.event.special.swipe[propertyName]  The link you reference in your comment will work. However, setting $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = 10, would achieve the same result.